# How to write model class with many relations?

Tags: django, django-models

I have class Person:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = ...
    [etc]
    client = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(ImageData, null=True)
```

This class contains data of persons and data of sellers.
And I have class Image. This model contains data of client images and data of sellers images. When seller create image field creator must be a Person relation to this seller:

```
class ImageData(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    [etc]
```

This classes definitions are in one file models.py. When class ImageData is first manage.py says:

```
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

When class Person is first:

```
NameError: name 'ImageData' is not defined
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you importing the class Person ?

Comment: No, both classes definitions are in one file

Comment: Can you post your entire models.py ? I think its possible you are defining ImageData before Person.

Comment: Ah I see the problem, you would need to define a Many to Many relationship: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Does this maybe solve your problem: creator = models.ForeignKey('your_appname.Person')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the model is not yet defined you can put the name as string, so that you don't get this kind of errors. So update your definitions as

```
image = models.ForeignKey('ImageData', null=True)
```

ie. quotes around `ImageData`.

From documentation here [ForiegnKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

*If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:*

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
    # ...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
```